# Нужно ли обособление в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Просто зайди и убедись, что ты не права, прежде чем оскорблять. Если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Просто зайди и убедись, (2) что ты не права, (3)прежде чем оскорблять.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с двумя придаточными, **запятые ставятся:** (1) — главное предложение, (2) — изъяснительное придаточное,  союз ЧТО, (3) — придаточное времени, союз ПРЕЖДЕ ЧЕМ.

Предложение (3) — односоставное инфинитивное.

Это неоднородное параллельное подчинение: опорное слово **убедись** (в чем? когда?), разные придаточные.